# How to reference to the parent from child in firebase database while showing in recyclerView usin Firebase UI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am currently referencing to the quote_text child. These data are showing in `recyclerview` using `firebase` UI. I want to get parent name of quote_text. How do you get parent name of quote_text child.

When user clicks favorite button then I want to get the quote_id and want to create another key. Please help me.
[image: Screen Shot]

## Here is code of my project:

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Quotes, QuoteHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull QuoteHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Quotes model) {
            Log.i("KK", "onBindViewHolder" + model.getQuote_text());
            Log.i("KK", "onBindViewHolder AUTHER" + model.getAuther());
            //Setting Quotes
            holder.setQuote(model.getQuote_text());

            //Setting Likes Count
            holder.setLikesCount(model.getLikes_count());
        }

        @Override
        public QuoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.quote_single_layout, parent, false);

            Log.i("KK", "Inflate" + view);

            return new QuoteHolder(view);
        }
    };
    Log.i("KK", "Adapter" + firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    mRecylerViewQuote.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
}

public class QuoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View view;

    //Two share and favorite image buttons
    private ImageButton mShareButton;
    private ImageButton mFavoriteButton;
    //String
    String quoteText;


    public QuoteHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;

        //initialization
        mShareButton = view.findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        mFavoriteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);

        //Click event Handling
        mShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Share Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, quoteText);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share Using:"));
            }
        });

        mFavoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Favorite Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                setFavoriteQuote()//Here I want to get parent name of 
                                  //quote_text......................
            }
        });

    }

    public void setQuote(String quote_text) {
        quoteText = quote_text;

        TextView mQuoteText = view.findViewById(R.id.quote_text);
        mQuoteText.setText("\"" + quote_text + "\"");

        if (mQuoteProgress.isShowing())
            mQuoteProgress.dismiss();
    }

    public void setLikesCount(int likes_count) {
        TextView mLikesCountText = view.findViewById(R.id.likes_count_text);
        Log.i("Count", String.valueOf(likes_count));
        mLikesCountText.setText(String.valueOf(likes_count) + "  Likes");

        if (mQuoteProgress.isShowing())
            mQuoteProgress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get **options**? If you have a Datasnapshot object you can access the key values by using getKey(). https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot

Comment: I used Firebase UI  open source library to populate data into the views. There is no any data snapshot option. Any other solution??

Comment: You can access the data snapshots in the adapter, check my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You can access the data snapshots by using the `getSnapshots()` method inside your adapter. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull QuoteViewHoler holder, int position, @NonNull Quote model) {
    this.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getKey();
}
```

Comment: I used this code snippet but problem is that the position is changing on each recyclerView scrolling. Wrong position key is arrived each time. Any other solution?

Comment: I didn't understand the problem, could you elaborate more?

Comment: When user clicks mFavoriteButton then I want to get key of that quote shown in database structure. I used Firebase ui to show the all the quotes of birthday in recyclerView. Now When user clicks favorite buttton of any specific quote then I want to get key of that quote and store that key on another index. And favorite quotes are placed in structure like: favorite_quote>quote_id and quote text