# How to get a child node of a Recycler View?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I've been having a hard time trying to access the child node of this item for my recyclerview.

I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640230/how-to-reference-to-the-parent-from-child-in-firebase-database-while-showing-in) solution and other solutions but none worked.

Basically as you can see from the picture(below) there are item 1 and item 2 displaying the recyclerview, but I want to set the texts that are in those items which is located in another node under the parent node.

This is my onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecipesHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final RecipesModel model) {
                holder.recipeName.setText(model.getName());
                holder.recipeCategory.setText(model.getCategory());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImageURL()).centerCrop().resize(widthInPX, heightInPX).into(holder.recipeImage);
                holder.recipeRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewRecipeActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("RecipeID", model.getId());
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

            }
```

This is my constructor (Not updated to fit database yet)

```
    public class RecipesModel {

    private String name, category, date, imageURL;
    private String id;

    public RecipesModel(){}

    public RecipesModel(String name, String category, String date, String imageURL, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.date = date;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

> I changed it back to original when my database was more simple and didn't have any child nodes.

[image]

I am also open to changing how my database structure is set up; For good reasons.

Thank you.

Comment: How does your `RecipesModel` look? Shouldn't it have `SnapInfo` field in it?

Comment: your right! its just a normal constructor with strings that has getters and setters I'm not sure how you would go on with creating it for SnapInfo. I've updated my answer. *NOTE its not what it's actually for because I've updated the database but not my constructor yet.